# How to access Song data using MediaPlayer in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I trying to access the song data information, like physical path, to read the song object from the file location, either from MediaPlayer or Song Element.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to know the physical path of a `Song` in order to play it. You can access the music on a user's device via the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary_members.aspx), which is found within the XNA framework. You can retrieve a [SongCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.songcollection.aspx) using the [Songs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.songs.aspx) property of the MediaLibrary. You can then iterate through the SongCollection and use the MediaPlayer to play it.

Comment: I am trying to convert the song object to binary data (convert to stream). If I don't have the physical location of the song, how can I do that... I not looking to play a song but trying read the data and convert it to another form and put in a different physical location.

Comment: @Praneeth AFAIK, that's not really possible because a Song filetype can only be played through the Media Player. Therefore, if it was possible to get a stream, then you'd be able to play it through MediaElements as well. I'd be happy to be corrected here, but I can only think of somehow redirecting audio to a buffer and using it with the DynamicSoundEffectInstance (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff434006.aspx).

Comment: Getting the stream is the problem. Playing the song with MediaElement and DynamicSoundEffectInstance is not a issue. There is no xna or silverlight method which will give bytes[] for the song object.